# devtools - send message to background page when all network requests are completed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have this code in my chrome extension (I'm making it for learning propouse)

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "test",
  "description": "test",
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "activeTab",
    "downloads"
  ],
  "minimum_chrome_version": "85.0",
  "devtools_page": "index.html",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "js/background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "browser_action": {
    
  },
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

devtools.js

```
let button = document.getElementById('process-data');
let fileChunks = [];

chrome.devtools.panels.create('test', '', '/index.html');

let port = chrome.runtime.connect({
  name: 'devtools'
});

// port.onMessage.addListener( (message) => {});

chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener( (request) => {
  if(request.response.status === 206 ){
    console.log(request);
    request.getContent( (content, encoding) => {
      let data = `data:audio/mpeg;base64,${content}`;
      fetch(data)
      .then( (res) => res.arrayBuffer() )
      .then( (buffer) => {
        console.log(buffer);
        fileChunks = [...buffer];
      });
    });
  }
});

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  port.postMessage({type: 'processBuffer', data: fileChunks});
});
```

What I want to do is to inspect network requests from a certain website and get the response body content. On this point all seems working fine, I've solved an issue related to the `request.method` that I don't know why is undefined and will cause that the extension wasn't working. Now I've implemented a simple messaging system with background page as you can see, I want to pass the retrived body content to the background page of the extension to process it. Since I don't know how to check if no request are made, I'm implementing a button to send the content to background for processing but I'm unable to access to the button that is in the panel
background.js

```
let chunks = [];

chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener( (port) => {
  let devtoolsListener = (message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if(message.type === 'processBuffer'){
      processChunks(message.data);
    }
  }
  port.onMessage.addListener(devtoolsListener);
  port.onDisconnect.addListener( () => {
    devToolsConnection.onMessage.removeListener(devToolsListener);
  });
});

const processChunks = async (chunks) => {
  console.log(chunks);
}
```

index.html

```
<script src="js/devtool.js"></script>

<button id="process-data">Process audio data</button>
```

These are the errors I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: buffer is not iterable
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
Error in event handler: ReferenceError: devToolsConnection is not defined
```

Is there any way to detect when a page complete all the requests so a message can be sent to background script to start data processing?

Comment: please upload your manifest

Comment: @ATP please see the updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your button just didn't create on the script run time.
change it to:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    let button = document.getElementById('process-data');
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
       port.postMessage({type: 'processBuffer', data: fileChunks});
   });
});
```

And I believe you want:

```
port.onMessage.removeListener(devToolsListener);
```

not

```
devToolsConnection.onMessage.removeListener(devToolsListener);
```